# Adding new Data rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to build a data frame so I can generate a Plot with a specific set of data, but I am having trouble getting the data into a table correctly.

So, here is what I have available from a data query:

```
> head(c, n=10)
               EVTYPE FATALITIES INJURIES
834           TORNADO       5633    91346
856         TSTM WIND        504     6957
170             FLOOD        470     6789
130    EXCESSIVE HEAT       1903     6525
464         LIGHTNING        816     5230
275              HEAT        937     2100
427         ICE STORM         89     1975
153       FLASH FLOOD        978     1777
760 THUNDERSTORM WIND        133     1488
244              HAIL         15     1361
```

I then tried to generate a set of data variables to build a finished a data.frame like this:

```
a <- c(c[1,1], c[1,2], c[1,3])
b <- c(c[6,1], c[4,2] + c[6,2], c[4,3] + c[6,3])
d <- c(c[2,1], c[2,2], c[2,3])
e <- c(c[3,1], c[3,2], c[3,3])
f <- c(c[5,1], c[5,2], c[5,3])
g <- c(c[7,1], c[7,2], c[7,3])
h <- c(c[8,1], c[8,2], c[8,3])
i <- c(c[9,1], c[9,2], c[9,3])
j <- c(c[10,1], c[10,2], c[10,3])
k <- c(c[11,1], c[11,2], c[11,3])
df <- data.frame(a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)
names(df) <- c("Event", "Fatalities","Injuries")
```

But, that is failing miserably.  What I am getting is a long string of all the data variables, repeated 10 times.  nice trick, but that is not what I am looking for.
I would like to get a finished data.frame with ten (10) rows of the data, like it was originally, but with my combined data in place.  Is that possible.
I am using R version 3.5.3. and the tidyverse library is not available for install on that version.
Any ideas as to how I can generate that data.frame?

Comment: Unclear (i) how `df` relates to the original dataframe and (ii) what you want to plot

Comment: It would help to have a clearer picture of what you end-result would look like (data and/or plot). From what you tried, it looks like you may just want to recode some of the data (combining HEAT and EXCESSIVE HEAT together in one row). Is that correct?

Comment: I would like to generate a time series plot of Event as my x axis and Fatalities as my dependent variable in one plot and injuries as the dependent variable in the other plot.

Comment: @Ben,  I wanted to compine Heat and Excessive Heat because they seem similar as an Event, but I can leave them as is if that is too much of a stretch.

Comment: @Chris  -  df is a brand new data.frame that I am creating on the merged data that from a-k.  Then, I want to create a time series plot with df.  I am not sure why you guys voted -2 on this question;

Comment: I didn't vote down. But the problem with your question is its lack in clarity. Maybe it would help if you say (i) what you wanted to achieve in transforming the original dataframe (is it called `c`? If so, that's unfortunate as `c` is also a very common function!) into `df` and (ii) what the plot looks like or is supposed to look like (e.g., constructed on some similar data).

Comment: @Chris,  Thank you for getting back to me.  I am learning R and Data Science and trying to understand the concepts and language at the same time,  Fun stuff...  I would like to generate either a barplot or a histogram with the EVTYPE as x and Fatalities and Injuries and y or height.  I can't seem to get that done with my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a barplot is what you're after, here's a piece of code to get you that:

First, you need to get the data in the right format (that's probably what you tried to do in `df`), by column-binding the two numerical variables using `cbind`and transposing the resulting dataframe using `t`(i.e., turning rows into columns and vice versa):

```
plotdata <- t(cbind(c$FATALITIES, c$INJURIES))
```

Then set the layout to your plot, with a wide margin for the x-axis to accommodate your long factor names:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar = c(8,3,3,3))
```

Now you're ready to plot the data; you grab the labels from `c$EVTYPE`, reduce the label size in `cex.names` and rotate them with `las` to avoid overplotting:

```
barplot(plotdata, beside=T, names = c$EVTYPE, col=c("red","blue"), cex.names = 0.7, las = 3)
```

(You can add `main =`to define the heading to your plot.)

That's the barplot you should obtain:
[image]

Comment: If I wanted to know how to do other plots in R, where would be a good source to read?  I read lots of link, but none was clear on how to prepare and finish the plot.  I even tried to use table, but that failed for me.

Comment: Does the code provide what you're looking for? That is, does it answer your question? If it does please click the green tick.

Comment: For other plot types, check out, for example, `?hist` for histograms, `?boxplot` for boxplots. But for your type of data the barplot seems the best option.

Comment: Take a quick look at histograms for your data: `hist(c$FATALITIES, breaks = 10, freq = F)
lines(density(c$FATALITIES, from = 0, to = 6000), col = "blue")
hist(c$INJURIES, breaks = 10, freq = F)
lines(density(c$INJURIES, from = 0, to = 1e+05), col = "blue")`

Comment: Might even wanna check out this (plots density lines for `INJURIES` and `FATALITIES`): `hist(c$INJURIES, main = "Densities", breaks = 10, freq = F, border = "white", ylim = c(0, 5.760e-04))
lines(density(c$INJURIES, from = 0, to = 1e+05), col = "red")
lines(density(c$FATALITIES), col = "blue")
legend("topright", c("INJURIES", "FATALITIES"), fill = c("red", "blue"), cex = 0.8, bty = "n")`